# Ошибка сегментирования(стек памяти сброшен на диск)

Tags: c++

Не понимаю,что вызвало ошибку в коде(я предполагаю, что двумерный массив,но не уверен), как её исправить и в чём она? Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");
  string comm,memb[1000],info[12][100];
  int n,num[1000];
  double membmoney[1000];

  cout << "Введите количество сотрудников: ";
  cin >> n;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    membmoney[i] = 0;
    memb[i] = "Сотрудник не найден";
  }

  cout<< "Введите имя и фамилию вашего сотрудника через '_'" << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cin >> memb[i];
  }
  cout << "Для начала напишите 'start'" << endl;

  cin >> comm;

  while (comm != "exit") {

    cout << "Выберите комманду:" << endl;
    cout << "0 - Запросить список всех сотрудников" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Запись значения зарплат для всех" << n << " сотрудников" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Изменение зарплаты определённого сотрудника" << endl;
    cout << "3 - Изменение зарплаты сотрудника на определённый процент" << endl;
    cout << "4 - Изменение зарплаты всех сотрудников на определённый процент" << endl;
    cout << "5 - Вывод информации о зарплате по определённому сотруднику" << endl;
    cout << "6 - Вывод информации о зарплате по всем сотрудникам компании" << endl;
    cout << "7 - Удаление сотрудника из базы" << endl;
    cout << "8 - Информация обо всех выплатах каждому из сотрудников за год" << endl;
    cout << "exit - Выход" << endl;

    cin >> comm;

    //0
    if (comm == "0") {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << memb[i] << " " << i + 1 << endl;
      }
    }

    //1
    if (comm == "1") {
      cout << "Введите зарплату сотрудника" << endl;
      int sum;
      for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int a = num[i];
        cin >> sum;
        membmoney[i] = sum;
        info[i][a] = "Сотруднику_номер_начислено_рублей";
        num[i] += 1;
      }
    }

    //2
    if (comm == "2") {
      cout << "Введите номер сотрудника и сумму изменения" << endl;
       int num,sum;
       cin >> num >> sum;
       membmoney[num - 1] += sum;
    }

    //3
    if (comm == "3") {
      cout << "Введите процент изменения и номер сотрудника" << endl;
      int proc, num;
      cin >> proc >> num;
      membmoney[num - 1] *= proc/100 + 1;
    }

    //4
    if (comm == "4") {
      cout << "Введите процент изменения";
      int proc;
      cin >> proc;
      for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        membmoney[i] *= proc/100 + 1;
      }
    }

    //5
    if (comm == "5") {
      cout << "Введите номер сотрудника: ";
      int num;
      cin >> num;
      cout<< "Зарплата сотрудника номер "<< num << ": "<< membmoney[num + 1] << " р.";
    }

    //6
    if (comm == "6") {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << memb[i] << " - " << membmoney[i] << " р." << endl;
      }
    }

    //7
    if (comm == "7") {
      n -= 1;
      cout << "Введите номер сотрудника, которого нужно удалить";
      int num;
      cin >> num;
      num -= 1;
      for (int i = num; i < n; ++i) {
        memb[i] = memb[i + 1];
      }
    }
  }

  //Andrey_Sitalo Marat_Zhurkin Name_Surname Namesur_Eman Imya_Familiya это для тестов имена
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: А написать, какие действия вызвали такую реакцию программы, вы не хотите? Как воспроизвести ситуацию?

Comment: так это и есть вопрос!

Comment: Первое, что бросилось в глаза - а что если сотрудников будет больше 12? и строка вот эта `info[12][100]`. я бы ее как минимум переписал в виде `info[1000][100]` ( Правда я так и не понял, зачем там этот двухмерный массив)

Comment: перепутал,думал это из-за размера массива и немного уменьшил,до этого было info[1000][100]

Comment: ошибка происходит при самом запуске программы

Comment: Нормально запускается, можно даже что-то вводить. Что ввести, чтобы получить неприятности?

Answer (score 0):

Массив `int num[1000];` при старте программы без начальных значений и равен по сути случайным индексам. Модификация массива `info`

```
int a = num[i];
...
info[i][a] = "Сотруднику_номер_начислено_рублей";
```

со случаным индексом `a = num[i]` приводит к ошибке памяти.

Задайте сначала эти значения нулю или коротко так :

```
int num[1000] = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Короче, зачастую, чтобы это исправить надо расширить стэк.
Вот [тут](https://losst.ru/oshibka-segmentirovaniya-ubuntu#%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) вам всё объяснят.